# How do I edit the css and html of my home.php file

Tags: php, html, css

I've just finished creating my login page and would like to edit the homepage users see when they log in. However, the page users are redirected to is home.php. I'm not confident enough with PHP to design the page in it so is there a way I can use html and css instead? Also, I want to add in the navbar I created.

My home.php code

```
<?php
// check to see if the user is logged in
if ($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    // user is logged in
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
} else {
    // user is not logged in, send the user to the login page
    header('Location: index.html');
}
?>
```

[image: My interface design made using word. (This is how I'm trying to design my home screen. It's for a school project]

Comment: You don't have to have a single bit of PHP code in a file named something.php so just do your thing with HTML and CSS in home.php.

Comment: First inlcude your CSS file into your page. Secondly, you can wrire HTML and CSS inside your PHP file.

Comment: oh ok, so I can get rid of the session log in stuff too and it will still work?

Comment: Move the `header('Location: index.html');` inside `if (! $_SESSION['loggedin'])` statement and remove the else.

then do you html, css and `include` below

Comment: all php does is use server side code to output html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, include the `homepage.php` in your `home.php`.

```
<?php
// check to see if the user is logged in
if ($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    // user is logged in
    include_once 'homepage.php';
} else {
    // user is not logged in, send the user to the login page
    header('Location: index.html');
}
?>
```

Then, create the `homepage.php` file in the same directory. It can have PHP code, HTML, CSS. Also, you can use PHP [to generate HTML](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/in-html).

Example `home.php`

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
    <p>Hello <?= $_SESSION['username' ?>,</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi O Sparks, welcome to Stack Overflow. James is showing a correct example of how you could approach your problem. PHP has nothing to do with showing basic HTML and CSS. You can do this without any problem. However, PHP can be used to add in additional logic to your page as well as show data. As long as you are not familiar with that, you do not have to worry about it.